# Leetcode #77 Combinations - Not sure what is wrong with this syntax

Tags: python, attributes

I am trying to learn python and am doing leetcode problems to become more familiar with the syntax. I am getting the error:

```
NameError: name 'dfs' is not defined
    dfs(result, temp, 0, n, k)
```

I am also not sure if I am declaring the lists correctly or if I should pass `self` as a parameter to the functions.

```
class Solution:
    def dfs(self, result: List[List[int]], temp:List[int], index: int, n: int, k: int):
        for i in range(index + 1, n + 1):
            temp.push(i)
            if len(temp) == k:
                result.push(temp)
                temp.pop()
                return 
            else:
                dfs(result, temp, i, n, k)
                temp.pop()
                
    def combine(self, n: int, k: int) -> List[List[int]]:
        result = [[]];
        temp = [];
        dfs(result, temp, 0, n, k)
        return result
```

Comment: Your syntax is fine, it's how you're referring to the functions that's the problem. BTW get rid of the semicolons; they do nothing.

Answer (score 2):

It should be `self.dfs(result, temp, 0, n, k)`. So change to `self.dfs` wherever you are using `dfs`

Answer (score 2):

In this example, `dfs` is a method on `Solution`, so when using it from other methods on `Solution` you want to call `self.dfs` instead of `dfs`. Alternatively, you could move the definition of `dfs` outside of the class, like so:

```
def dfs(...):
   ...

class Solution:
   ...
```

I assume that the reason these are methods on a class is something about the format of leetcode's interface that requires the use of classes rather than free-standing functions, but probably it would be more idiomatic in Python for `dfs` to be a free-standing function rather than a method in most cases. Generally if something doesn't need to use the `self` argument and doesn't need to be called by something that only has a reference to a specific object, there's no need to make it a method.

Comment: Yeah this seems to be a quirk of Leetcode. It might be more idiomatic to make `dfs` a `staticmethod`, but yeah ideally it would be a free-standing function.

Answer (score 1):

It's not the best idea to use `itertools.combinations` for solving these algorithm problems, but just in case you didn't know, here we can solve the problem with that.

This'll pass:

```
class Solution:
    def combine(self, n, k):
        return tuple(itertools.combinations(range(1, n + 1), k))
```

Here are some of LeetCode's solutions with comments, implementing the same idea:

```
class Solution:
    def combine(self, n: int, k: int) -> List[List[int]]:
        # init first combination
        nums = list(range(1, k + 1)) + [n + 1]
        
        output, j = [], 0
        while j < k:
            # add current combination
            output.append(nums[:k])
            # increase first nums[j] by one
            # if nums[j] + 1 != nums[j + 1]
            j = 0
            while j < k and nums[j + 1] == nums[j] + 1:
                nums[j] = j + 1
                j += 1
            nums[j] += 1
            
        return output
```

With backtracking:

```
class Solution:
    def combine(self, n: int, k: int) -> List[List[int]]:
        def backtrack(first = 1, curr = []):
            # if the combination is done
            if len(curr) == k:  
                output.append(curr[:])
            for i in range(first, n + 1):
                # add i into the current combination
                curr.append(i)
                # use next integers to complete the combination
                backtrack(i + 1, curr)
                # backtrack
                curr.pop()
        
        output = []
        backtrack()
        return output
```

---

### References

- For additional details, please see the [Discussion Board](https://leetcode.com/problems/combinations/discuss) which you can find plenty of well-explained accepted solutions in there, with a variety of [languages](https://support.leetcode.com/hc/en-us/articles/360011833974-What-are-the-environments-for-the-programming-languages-) including efficient algorithms and asymptotic [time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_complexity)/[space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Space_complexity) complexity analysis<sup>[1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation), [2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Analysis_of_algorithms)</sup>.

Answer (score 1):

If you declare the functions inside the `Solution` class, then you have to refer to them as `self.dfs(...)` only if you don't want to do that, then write your function outside the `Solution` class. Something like this:

```
def dfs(...):
    # your body

class Solution(..):
    def combine(...):
```

And also, in Python, it is not 'push' for lists it is 'append' so please replace `temp.push` to `temp.append`